# embedding sections of live, read-only text in MS Word 365

Tags: microsoft-word, read-only

`doc1.docx` contains sections of 'master' text.  I want to insert these individually, as sections, into `doc2.docx`.  Those sections should:

1. update in `doc2` when the underlying text updates in `doc1`; this need not be automatic, but could be in response to a 'pull' request.
2. be read-only, so not be editable within `doc2`.
   Finally, I want to be able to add new text in `doc2`, around the inserted sections.

How do I do this?

Comment: See also Boiler by Word MVP Graham Mayor. http://www.gmayor.com/Boiler.htm

Answer (score 0):

You will have to split the master file into smaller documents, since
Word only supports the insert of live text of an entire document,
meaning not of a section of the document.

To create a live link :

- Place the cursor where the text is to be inserted
- In the Insert pane, Text group, click Object
- In the dialog, position to the tab "Create from File"
- Browse to your file
- Check "Link to File"
- Click OK.

From the article : [image]

This will create a read-only object in the document that contains
the text of the linked document. The text should update automatically
when the other document changes, but you may force it by right-click
and selecting "Update Link".

Comment: I believe this will allow editing of the linked text, will it not? Of course updating the link would erase any edits.

Comment: The linked document can be updated, but not the document that is linking to it.